# Точность вычислений в Wolfram|Alpha

Tags: математика, запрос

Какой оператор используется в [Wolfram|Alpha](http://www.wolframalpha.com/) для установки в запросе требуемой точности вычислений (знаков после запятой)?

Comment: Справку не пробовали смотреть? [compute a decimal approximation to a specified number of digits](http://www.wolframalpha.com/examples/ArbitraryPrecision.html)

Comment: @AlexKrass, Так автору же вроде не это нужно?

Comment: @s8am у автора стоит вопрос как установить количество `(знаков после запятой)`. В справке есть ответ, надо писать `to 1000 digits` или `50 digits of` для вывода ответа до определенного знака. Ну можно еще предположить, что имелись ввиду функции `ceiling, floor, round`, но это называется округлением и автор на этот счет ничего не написал.

Comment: @AlexKrass, `to N digits` задает общее количество знаков числа, а не количество знаков после запятой – я об этом.

Comment: @s8am сразу бы так и написали, а я не заметил этого поведения, действительно. Тогда все таки придется использовать математическое округление по типу `Floor(pi, 1E-2)`.

Comment: Ответ напишите уже в конце концов...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

---

Для того, чтобы явно указать **требуемое количиство знаков**, следует добавить в запрос `ЧИСЛО_ЗНАКОВ digits of аргумент`, [например](https://www.wolframalpha.com/input/?i=3%20digits%20of%20pi):

```
3 digits of pi
```

---

Для того, чтобы явно указать **требуемую точность округления**, следует обернуть запрос в функцию `Floor(аргумент, точность)`, [например](https://www.wolframalpha.com/input/?i=Floor%28pi%2C%201E-2%29):

```
Floor(pi, 1E-2)
```